# How can I fix the timeout issues in this dashboard?

Tags: javascript, html, dashboard

I have found this code in the internet and have been trying to make it work in my environment. At a first glance, it is working fine but the problem is that it is displaying the first page for some 50+ seconds and the second one for never more than 10. Where is that weird timeout setting is coming from?

```
<html lang=en>
<head>
<title>Checkpoint Dashboard</title>
<style type=text/css>
body, html { margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; }
iframe { border: none; }
</style>
<script type=text/javascript>
var Dash = {
  nextIndex: 0,
  dashboards: [
    {url: "https://host/html_draft0.html", time: 10},
    {url: "https://host/html_draft1.html", time: 10}
    ],

  display: function()
  {
      var dashboard = Dash.dashboards[Dash.nextIndex];
      frames["displayArea"].location.href = dashboard.url;
      Dash.nextIndex = (Dash.nextIndex + 1) % Dash.dashboards.length;
      setTimeout(Dash.display, dashboard.time * 5000);
  }
};
window.onload = Dash.display;
</script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe name="displayArea" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think if you remove `setTimeout(Dash.display, dashboard.time * 5000);` the 50 second timeout is removed.

Comment: Thanks @PeterSH, when I do that, it just stays on the first page and does not move on.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue, for me the timeout is 50 seconds for every page. maybe your hosts timeout the connection.

Comment: Strangely enough, it seems to be working fine reducing the multiplier to 1000. =/